# How does import really work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, import, export

I am having trouble understanding how import works in Javascript. Is it not supposed to just import the named function.

Here are my 2 files -

test.js -

```
export const add = (a,b) => {
    return a+b
}

export const subtract = (a,b) => {
    return a-b
}

console.log(add(7,7))

console.log(subtract(6,7))
```

and index.js

```
import { add } from './test.js'

console.log(add(4,5));
```

When running node index.js here is the output

```
14

-1

9
```

Why is the import also running the function calls in test.js

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The entire test.js is loaded and executed, there's no way to pick just a single part of the file to load.

Comment: Imported modules are executed. Why do you expect these two lines not to be executed? How would you design a module loader that loads JS modules, written in JS code, but without executing the code that does not relate to an `export`? If you were able to do this, then you’d break maths. This is provably impossible.

Comment: it works exactly as in browser. if you place imperative code in the root of a script, it will get executed. If you place it inside a function, it will only get run when you run the function containing it. How else do you expect anything reading that file to know what's declared inside, other than by executing the code inside of it, whether it's declarative or imperative?

Answer (score 2):

In js import works in a way that the imported modules are invoked first wherever you place your import statements in your file and after that your current file is executed. That's how js works!